# Why my sass mixins fails to work

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I make a sass mixin to do media query stuff, and I just cannot make it to work in my project. Even when I put `'display:none;'`, it still shows, which means that the media query i coded is not working. Am I missing something?

Actually when I change the `@mixin mq($media)` to 
`@media only screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 200px)`, it did work as expected.
 Besides, i also change $wide-desktop:em-calc(1500); to $wide-desktop:1500, and it's still not working as expected.

Thanks in advance.

My code is as follows:

```
$s:em-calc(380);
$ls:em-calc(492);
$tablet:em-calc(584);
$wide-tablet:em-calc(961);
$desktop:em-calc(1025);
$wide-desktop:em-calc(1500);
$tabletUp: em-calc(900);

@mixin mq($media) {
  @if $media == s {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $s) and (max-width: $ls - 1) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $media == ls {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $ls) and (max-width: $tablet - 1) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $media == tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $tablet) and (max-width: $wide-tablet - 1) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $media == wide-tablet {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $wide-tablet) and (max-width: $desktop - 1) { @content; }
  }  
  @else if $media == desktop {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $desktop) and (max-width: $wide-desktop - 1) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $media == wide-desktop {
    @media only screen and (min-width: $wide-desktop) { @content; }
  }

  @else if $media == tabletUp {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: $wide-desktop - 1) { @content; }
  }

}

@include mq(s){

        #header2{
              height:95%!important;
              #innerTop{margin-top:15%;display:none;}
        }

        .center section#move{height:5%!important;}
        div.center{
              top:95%!important;
        }

        #innerTop{

            margin-top:22%!important;
            h1{
               font-weight: 800;font-family:sans-serif;font-size: 3.4em!important;line-height: 63px;margin-top: 0;margin-left:0.5em;
               margin-bottom: 20px;color: white;max-width:70%;line-height:1.2em;
               span.h11{display:none;font-size:0.5em;}
           }
           p{
             font-size:1.1em;margin-left:1.5em;max-width:80%;margin-top:2em;margin-bottom:-1em; color:#e3e3e3;
             }

        }

}
```

Comment: Which version of `SASS` are you using ?

Comment: @ Mike Vranckx, I just checked and it's Sass 3.4.20, Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have the `em-calc` function declared somewhere in your project?

Comment: Nope, I thought sass have that function. And i used to use it months ago.and it was working then.

Comment: `em-calc` is part of Zurb Foundation not from SASS. Include that framework or assign directly the `em` values to your variables

Comment: We have no idea what "does not work" means in this context.  Did you look at the compiled CSS?  How does it differ from what you were expecting it to be?

Comment: em-calc is part of Zurb Foundation , and i found i import the sass mixins before the foundation framework. Maybe that's the reason why it does not work. and thanks. Can you make your answer below so i can make your anser the right one,Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is related to the missing `em-calc` function which generated your media query like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: em-calc(380)) and (max-width: em-calc(492) (-1))
```

Be sure that the function exists, or use directly the `em` values (based on 16px base font size)

```
$s: 23.750em;
...
```